# Getting information on a machine's hardware in Linux

Tags: linux, hardware, system-information

How can I check what hardware I have? (With BIOS version etc.)

Comment: On what Operating System ? There is no standard command so anything would be more or less distribution specific.

Comment: @jiliargre I wouldn't say *distribution specific* but certainly OS, Linux and BSD probably greatly vary here.

Comment: And Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, whatever too. That's what I meant.

Comment: @jll It's tagged [linux], so I suppose...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your system supports a **procfs**, you can get much information of your running system. Its an interface to the kernels data structures, so it will also contain information about your hardware. For example to get details about the used CPU you could `cat /proc/cpuinfo`
For more information you should see the *[man proc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)*.

More hardware information can be obtained through the kernel ring buffer logmessages with `dmesg`. For example this will give you a short summary of recently attached hardware and how it is integreated in the system.

These are some basic "interfaces" you will have on every distribution to obtain some hardware information.

Other 'small' tools to gather hardware information are:

- lspci - PCI Hardware
- lsusb - USB Hardware

Depending on your distribution you will also have access to one of these two tools to gather a detailed overview of your hardware configuration:

- [lshw](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter)
- hwinfo (SuSE specific but availible under other distributions also)

The "gate" to your hardware is thorugh the *"Desktop Management Interface"* (-> DMI). This framework will expose your system information to your software and is used by lshw for example. A tool to interact directly with the DMI is **[dmidecode](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/)** and availible on the most distributions as package. It will come with `biosdecode` which shows you also the complete availbile BIOS informations.

Answer (score 9):

To display a nice overview of my hardware, I use `lshw -short`, best run ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)). You can just run `lshw` plain of course, but I prefer the conciseness that the `-short` option offers.

To check my HDD usage, I use `df --human-readable`, which should be available by default on your system (unlike `lshw`).

Also, have a look at [checking hardware on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/checking-hardware-on-linux).

Comment: hwinfo is another nice utility and lm-sensors for temperatures.

Comment: @Patkos It seems `sudo hwinfo --short` is the equivalent, and it displays IMO prettier output. Unfortunately skips some interesting info (EG, it doesn't display HDD partition sizes).

Comment: lshw -html > file.html  generates a nice HTML formatted version. I find it much easier to go through it in a browser than a console window.

Comment: @ivanivan nice one. Is it new?

Comment: it was an option i had to specifically enable when i built it using gentoo back in 2002-3ish...

Answer (score 6):

You can use 'lshw'. Install it using 'sudo apt-get install lshw' on Debian and derivatives.
There's even a graphical version called lshw-gtk.

Answer (score 5):

This is highly variable between unix variants. Check the column for your variant on the [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html).

Under Linux, [lshw](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter) collects a lot of information scattered in various text files under `/proc` and `/sys`.

Answer (score 2):

for cpu info

`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

for disk usage

`df -h`

for pci cards and buses

`lspci`

you may find `lshw` useful

if you need usb devices

`lsusb`

Answer (score 1):

[HW Probe](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxhw/hw-probe/) — is an option to list all your hardware devices and make diagnostics of operability. It's based on hwinfo, lspci, lsusb, dmidecode and other tools.

[image: Screenshot of the report]