# Command-line-friendly full-text indexing?

Tags: command-line, search

Is there such a thing as a full-text indexing engine, that can be queried from the command line and ideally wouldn't require using a gui at all ?

I'm especially interested in indexing my ebooks and papers, so that's a mixture of pdf, epub and a few djvu. (Open)Office docs would be nice, but much lower on my list.

Comment: can you be more specific about what format the index takes?

Comment: Good point, edited.

Comment: -1 As pointed out below Lucene or Tracker are good choices, but what's your problem with "use gtk, or even worse qt" ? Using just the command line is fine, but I don't see the point of criticizing a set of libraries...

Comment: @tmow: point taken, question edited. Didn't mean to undermine anyone's hard work, sorry if that's how it came through...

Answer (score 12):

Have you looked at Lucene or Sphinx?  While you will need to initially parse the documents you want to index, once that's done, either one can search from the cli.

For Lucene, there is some info on doing this [available](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_can_I_index_file_formats_like_OpenDocument_.28aka_OpenOffice.org.29.2C_RTF.2C_Microsoft_Word.2C_Excel.2C_PowerPoint.2C_Visio.2C_etc.3F).

Sphinx, is a bit more vague, but there is also some documentation [available](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#xmlpipe2). You can pass structured XML data of your choice to sphinx via the xmlpipe2 data source.

Lucene relies on Java, while Sphinx is built in C++ with no needed outside dependencies.

Either one is going to require a bit of work to do what you want, but, seems like a totally workable solution.

Comment: As an aside, if you want to index data that's in a DB (postrgres, mysql) then either of these also work incredibly well.

Comment: hmm, I had dismissed sphinx for being too low-level, but looking at xmlpipe2 it seems a wrapper script for pdf2txt or the like would be pretty easy...

Comment: +1 for mentioning in Lucene. I had good times with Lucene, it is a killer stuff!!

Comment: I believe [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) is based on lucene, and might be more convenient to use (being a higher-level thing).

Comment: Fist link for lucene takes me to a confluence page that requires a login ... if Lucene is meant to be such a great tool, why is barrier to entry for it so high ??? i downloaded the software, ran luke.sh , all i want to do is pass a directory , create an index , then run a query, but instead i have to parse command line options , find syntax, add "unsupported" jdk modules, etc. Think i will look elsewhere ! I expected more from an apache project

Comment: @niken - I added that link 12 years ago...seems like it's no longer pointing to the right place!  I'll see if I can find a better one.

Answer (score 6):

check out [xapian](http://xapian.org/features). It has command line interface and can index a lot of formats.

Comment: xapian is a great index, my personal favorite, and it's written in native C++!.  Something which uses xapian would be most ideal, for many projects requiring indexing +1.

Answer (score 6):

[Recoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoll) can be built with no GUI and will search your document types from the command line.

It uses [Xapian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xapian) under the hood.

Comment: I've found `recoll` pretty good. `tracker` is an interesting option too.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69299/grep-of-many-keywords-over-many-files-speeding-it-up#69310) recommends using Google's [codesearch](https://code.google.com/p/codesearch/),

> Code Search is a tool for indexing and then performing regular
>   expression searches over large bodies of source code.

Superusers on Debian/derivatives can try: `sudo apt-get install codesearch`

Comment: this answer has some details on installing from source; in case it's not available in repos for your OS: https://superuser.com/a/1263343/65975

Answer (score 4):

Tracker can be invoked from the command line and gtk+ is not a hard dependency for a project (but may be for packages).

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaken, it'll still try to pull (large parts of) gnome as a dependency.

Comment: As I said - project (in version 0.9.x at least the only GNOME hard dependency is glib). Packages may compiled the sane-default staff like GUI so you may need to compile it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

There currently are two streams of Tracker, stable (0.8) and unstable (0.9). Your OS likely has the 0.8 version, so if you can afford it (it has some [bleeding edge](http://git.gnome.org/browse/tracker/tree/configure.ac) software dependencies), go grab the latest tarfile (0.9.x). It has [lots of improvements](http://live.gnome.org/Tracker/Roadmap) over 0.8, and is currently [being stabilized](http://pvanhoof.be/blog/index.php/2011/01/26/all-quiet-on-the-tracker-front) further in order to be 0.10 (even numbers represent stability). If you choose to go this route, use this command to configure:

```
./configure --disable-tracker-needle --disable-tracker-preferences --disable-tracker-explorer --disable-tracker-status-icon
```

You are likely not going to have the dependencies installed, so it should be esier to simply install 0.8 from your distro, and just avoid the GUI bits. On Debian Squeeze, Ubuntu 10.10, and Ubuntu 11.04, these are nicely split. So ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)) run:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends tracker-utils tracker-miner-fs
```

The CLI tool for this is `tracker-search`, so run it with the `--help` option to see how to take advantage of it :-)

**notes**:

- On Fedora 14, the Tracker package has dependencies on GTK+. I guess it's because it includes things like `tracker-applet` and `tracker-preferences`. They do however have a separate package for `tracker-search-tool`, the GUI search interface.
- DjVu and ePUB aren't (yet) supported. Here's [a list of of what is](http://live.gnome.org/Tracker/SupportedFormats).

Comment: Tracker is so refreshingly easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on writing a full text search tool (a new apropos) for indexing and searching man pages for NetBSD this summer using Sqlite3. It consists of two command line tools:

- makemandb: Which parses and builds an index of the content of man pages.
- apropos: The tool for querying this index.

You could easily write a similar tool for yourself, for pdf's you will need a library for parsing pdf documents and similarly a utility to parse the open office documents.

You can read more about the project [here](http://abhinav-upadhyay.blogspot.com/2011/08/final-report-netbsd-gsoc-2011-apropos.html)

The code is [here](https://github.com/abhinav-upadhyay/apropos_replacement)