# Command-line tool to search docx files

Tags: grep, search, cygwin, microsoft-word

Is there a command-line tool to text-search a docx file? I tried `grep`, but it doesn't work with docx even though it works fine with txt and xml files. I could convert the docx to txt first, but I'd prefer a tool that operates directly on docx files. I need the tool to work under Cygwin.

OP edit: Later I found out that the easiest way to achieve the grep is actually to convert those docx to txt then grep over them.

Comment: Related [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1258590/855954).

Comment: Related: [Command-line-friendly full-text indexing?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3086)

Comment: Apache Tika https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tika

Answer (score 7):

My `grep` solution as a function you can paste in your `.bashrc`

```bsh
docx_search(){ local arg wordfile terms=() root=${root:-/}; for arg; do terms+=(-e "$arg"); done; find 2>/dev/null "${root%/}/" -iname '*.docx' -exec bash -c "$(declare -p terms)"'; for arg; do unzip -p "$arg" 2>/dev/null | grep --quiet --ignore-case --fixed-strings "${terms[@]}" && printf %s\\n "$arg"; done' _ {} +; }
```

It will look for any (case insensitive) occurence of its arguments and print the matching docx file location.

---

Examples:

```bsh
$ docx_search 'my example sentence'
/cygdrive/d/example sentences.docx
/cygdrive/c/Users/my user/Documents/example sentences.docx
$ root='/cygdrive/c/Users/my user/' docx_search 'seldom' 'full sentence'
/cygdrive/c/Users/my user/Documents/example sentences.docx
$
```

---

Readable version:

```bsh
docx_search(){
  local arg wordfile terms=() root=${root:-/}
  # this 'root' assignment allows you to search in a specific location like /cygdrive/c/ instead of everywhere on the machine
  for arg; do terms+=(-e "$arg"); done
  # We inject the terms to search inside the string with declare -p`
  find 2>/dev/null "${root%/}/" -iname '*.docx' -exec \
    bash -c "$(declare -p terms)"';
      for arg; do
        unzip -p "$arg" 2>/dev/null |
          grep --quiet --ignore-case --fixed-strings "${terms[@]}" &&
          printf %s\\n "$arg"
      done' _ {} +
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know of several indexing tools that support Word documents. Such tools allow you to index documents, then efficiently search words in the index. They don't permit full text searches.

- [Recoll](http://www.recoll.org/) (with [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) and [WvWare](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/)). I don't know about Cygwin support.
- [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), with [some assembly required](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_can_I_index_file_formats_like_OpenDocument_.28aka_OpenOffice.org.29.2C_RTF.2C_Microsoft_Word.2C_Excel.2C_PowerPoint.2C_Visio.2C_etc.3F). Works on Cygwin, I believe.
- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), with [any docx-to-text converter](http://wiki.mailspect.com/index.php/README.sphinx#Adding_support_for_.doc_and_.docx). [Natively supported on Windows](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#installing-windows).
- [Tracker](http://live.gnome.org/Tracker/) ([there may still be some kinks](http://live.gnome.org/Tracker/SupportedFormats)). Cygwin support looks iffy.

Answer (score 2):

DOCx is compressed and it is not a text format. So what you need is a [converter](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/) first. After that you can use the `find` command on the converted file(s).

Comment: Or you can use a search tool that can read inside compressed files. In your last sentence, I suppose you meant `grep`?

Comment: @Gilles - look at the original title of the question before Michael edited it. This seemed to be a question about DOS (and I flagged it off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version optimized for performance.

It requires `ripgrep` and `fd-find`. Here's how to install them if you do not have them.

**fd-find:**

```
sudo apt install fd-find
```

**ripgrep:**

```
curl -LO https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases/download/13.0.0/ripgrep_13.0.0_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./ripgrep_13.0.0_amd64.deb
```

Paste this in your `.bashrc`:

```bash
docxgrep() {
    
    keyword="$1"
    
    /usr/bin/fdfind -t f -e docx . | while read -r arg; do
        if unzip -p "$arg" 2>/dev/null | rg -q  --ignore-case --fixed-strings "$keyword"; then
            echo "$arg"
        fi
    done
}
```

Run `source ~/.bashrc`
Now we can search:

```bash
$ docxgrep 'hello'        
./Document.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [openoffice ninja](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/convert-openxml-docx-etc-in-linux-using.html)?
(don't know about cygwin support)