# fdisk unable to open

Tags: ubuntu, fdisk

I am having problems using `fdisk` to clear the partition table of my sd card. The sd card is identified in the `/dev` folder when inserted into the sd card reader, but when the following command in run:

```
fdisk /dev/sde
```

the response in the terminal is:

> unable to open sde

I have also tried using `sde1`, which is the partition on the sd card, and it still failed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you include the output of dmesg after attaching your sd card?

Comment: Are you doing it as root?

Answer (score 4):

Like, Falmarri indicated in his comment, you are not running `fdisk` [as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root).

The easiest way to do this, is to run:

```
$ sudo fdisk <path-to-drive>
```