# Forcing emacs to run with `-nw` when called from terminal

Tags: shell, emacs

**note**: This question might have been asked before ( I think I saw it somewhere), but a quick search did not reveal anything.

I would like to tell the difference when a command is run from a shell.

Emacs can be initialized with the `-nw` flag to disable the **gui** window, and I want this to be the default behaviour. However if `emacs` is run from a non-shell environment, ( e.g. from the `Open With` in your **filemanager**, a **desktop configured hotkey**, or even from **bashrun** ), it should not be called with the `-nw` flag.

**update**: This should be a global change, running `sudo emacs` in Terminal should'nt suddenly open a gui. Where do I make these changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to determine if a command is run in a *terminal*.

```
if [ -t 2 ]; then
  # Standard error is a terminal
  emacs -nw "$@"
elif [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  # An X display is available
  xterm -e emacs -nw "$@"
else
  # We have nothing
  emacs --daemon "$@"
fi
```

---

If you want this to always happen when you run Emacs, put it in a script and invoke that script instead. You can call the script `/usr/local/bin/emacs` (assuming Linux) if you want it to be called `emacs` and invoked in preference to the “real” `emacs` executable in `/usr/bin`.

Note that to [edit files as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root/3064#3064), you should use `sudoedit` (benefits: the editor runs as you so you get all your settings; the edited file is put into place atomically when you finish editing, reducing the chance of a mishap). You can also edit files as root directly inside Emacs by opening `/sudo::/path/to/file`.

Answer (score 9):

Say this:

```
$ echo "alias emacs='emacs -nw'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Log out, then log back in, and you will get the behavior you are asking for. The alias applies only to Bash.

Comment: and how do I get passed **bashrun**?

Comment: According to the manual, `bashrun` doesn't read `~/.bashrc`.  If the manual is wrong, you can say "unalias emacs" in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/bashrun/rc to remove the alias for `bashrun`.

Comment: mmm... you win! but.. Gilles wins more :) ( I want to cover more than just bash )

Comment: @Stefan I think most shells load from `.bashrc`; if they don't they almost certainly have an equivalent configuration file you could put the same line in

Comment: @Michael, I don't want to store the same config setting in two different files, that is just bad practise. Also, I used `emacs` from `sh`, it opened a **gui** instead.

Comment: @Stefan Well, `ln -s .bashrc .whateverrc`. Or use `.profile`, etc.

Comment: Putting my solution into `.profile` will work if `/bin/sh` is Bash or another shell that understands aliases, but that is not the case on all systems.  That said, I don't see why it really matters.  `/bin/sh` exists for running shell scripts, not for interactive use, which use of X implies.  If you have a shell script you wrote for use interactively, instead of trying to shoehorn my solution into working for `/bin/sh`, just put `#!/bin/bash` or whatever at the top instead.

Comment: I'll be damned, I tried it some time ago and it didn't work. Then I retested it this morning (probably doing some stupid thing) with the same result. I just now RE-added the alias (alias emacs='emacs -nw') and it works... Removing previous comment and +1-ing.