# How to make a distro be fullscreen on VirtualBox?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I'm running Debian as host and I fail to get Debian, Ubuntu, and Fedora guests to be fullscreen. Changing video memory didn't help.

**NOTES**:

- I haven't tried any other distro
- I didn't create WinXP guest myself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be in place. You need to have guest additions installed on the guest OS. You have to have "guest display auto-resize" feature enabled (<kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> toggles this), and then you have to actually activate full-screen mode (<kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> toggles this).

Specifically, on the Debian/Ubuntu guest, run the following ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/688)):

```
apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
```

Comment: Guest additions not being installed is almost certainly the problem

Comment: Agreed with Falmarri. Most distributions have the guest additions in the repositories, so you can look there first.

Comment: I followed the instructions and now I got "Disable Guest Display Auto-resize" and it's not selectable. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the guest additions correctly? You compiled/installed/restarted?

Comment: @Fal, must I restart the host as well?

Comment: Hm.  I don't think it's necessary to restart the host, but it might give you peace of mind if you do. Another thing to try would be shutting off the virtual machine (instead of just letting the guest reboot itself).

Comment: @Tshepang: You shouldn't need to restart the host, but I would try that anyway.

Comment: @Shawn & @Fai, restarted both host (Debian 6.0 - Squeeze) and guest (Ubuntu 10.10), and having VBox guest additions installed on the guest. "Disable Guest Display Auto-resize" is still not selectable.

Comment: It's definitely worth going to the project's forums (http://forums.virtualbox.org/) and asking there. They will have in-depth knowledge and experience that is harder to come across in a general community.

Comment: Wait, are you trying both a debian VM and a ubuntu VM? Or is debian your host and ubuntu your guest? It could be a debian driver thing, I'm not sure. I've only ever run VMs in ubuntu

Comment: @fal Am trying both Debian and Ubuntu VM on Debian host.

Comment: @Tshepang: Is this working for you now? If not, what virtualbox packages do you have installed?

Comment: When I followed Shawn Goff's answer and tried `apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11` I got the package not found error. It DID work with `apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11` Apparently the package has been re-named.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo -i
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall
```

‍`reboot‍`

```
sudo -i
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Comment: What CD is that on?

Comment: This question is already answered and  with it's age you need to provide more detail.  I'm recommending deletion 4 now.