# Adjusting Screen Size on Ubuntu Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, display-settings

When running Ubuntu as a Vitualbox guest, with a Windows 7 64-bit machine as host, how can I maximize the screen so it fills up the whole monitor?

Comment: Do you find @Anton's answer insufficient? If so, please comment on what else you're looking for. If it solved your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Duplicate? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/how-to-make-a-distro-be-fullscreen-on-virtualbox

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to install virtualbox guest additions (virtualbox-ose-guest-utils package). Screen size will resize then automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Under Ubuntu 12.04 I first had to install the virtualbox guest additions. And after that I also had to go to "System Settings" -> "Hardware - Additional Drivers" and activate "Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module", because by default it was still de-activated.