# Network monitoring tool

Tags: networking, software-rec, monitoring, bandwidth

I'm basically looking for a utility that displays which processes are using how much bandwidth, similar to how `top` displays which processes use how much resources.

Comment: whats FLOSS? Something like Free L? Open Source Software?

Comment: Ah thanks :-) its because to indicate the difference of free/open source :-)

Comment: @echox I got rid of the acronym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) is the best tool I have found so far that fulfills my need, but sadly needs to be run [as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/). ([via](https://superuser.com/questions/29752/how-to-track-lan-usage-aka-top-for-lan))

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [ntop.org](http://www.ntop.org).

Comment: How do you get it to display BW consumption per process? Look at my Answer to see what I'm looking for. Can this do that, or close enough?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add iptraf to the list. http://iptraf.seul.org

Comment: I see last update was 2005, and that's worrying. Why do you recommend it? Why use it instead of alternatives?

Comment: Simple to install, simple to use and useful. I started using it about 10 years ago, and never needed a replacement. I am still using it. Netstat shows you just a snapshot (like ps for processes), ntop gives you something like top for the network ... I don't know about NetHogs. You also can use lsof to see which process uses which port if you need.

Answer (score 0):

netstat can give you usage statistics on a per socket basis.

Comment: What command do you use to get *usage statistics on a per socket basis*? Can you get usage on a per-process basis?

Answer (score 0):

IMO in decreasing order of usefulness, if you want to know what's eating your bandwidth. Of course, to just list and monitor sockets  you can `watch -d 'sudo ss -tlpn'`.

#### Bandwidth monitor with process info

- [bandwhich](https://github.com/imsnif/bandwhich): Terminal bandwidth utilization tool. On brew.
- [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs): Net top tool grouping bandwidth per process. On Debian repos.

```bash
# Show connection but not processes
iptraf-ng
iptop
```

```bash
# Up/down each second
ifstat -bt
sar -n DEV  1
```

- Other general stats Realtime network interface monitors: Also general stats... (all on Debian repos)

  - [bmon](http://www.infradead.org/%7Etgr/bmon/)
  - [vnstat](https://humdi.net/vnstat/).  Check also [this answer].(https://askubuntu.com/a/846455/349837)
  - [nload](http://www.roland-riegel.de/nload/)
  - [slurm](https://github.com/mattthias/slurm)
  - [tcptrack](http://www.rhythm.cx/%7Esteve/devel/tcptrack/)
  - Maybe [`atop`](https://www.atoptool.nl/screenshots.php), using `netatop` kernel module.

Answer (score -1):

You can get stats from `netstat` via the `-s` flag, and per-process from the `-p` flag.

Comment: Yet it doesn't really show per application bandwidth.