# Is there a way for a normal person like me to create a linux GUI like Cinnamon or Gnome?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, desktop

So, I am trying to create my own Linux distro based off of Ubuntu (called "Cubuntu" and pronounced "Chew-buntu") and I was wondering if I could create my own GUI or desktop environment for cheap or free.

Comment: weird question to ask... how are we suppose to know of you can? heck you don't even list what kind of languages you can code in. Short version: others have so ... I assume the answer is yes.  Need to be proficient in coding though.

Comment: Of course you can; you just take the latest debian and distribute it under your "chubuntu" name ;-)

Comment: If you have to go to a forum to ask this, then no. On a brighter note, you can learn to customize any Ubuntu and release your CodyKishubuntu, it will look different, but be the same. Rather ask yourself what you want to be different. maybe Gnome can be easily adapted to meet this need.

Comment: I don't understand the part about "normal person".

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** you can take an existing Linux distro, modify it, work out the bugs, then even publish your modifications, all for free.  It'll cost you *time* of course, but in exchange you'll learn a lot.

See also:

- [How to start a new Linux distro?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/how-to-start-a-new-linux-distro)
- [How to easily build your own Linux Distro?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87011/how-to-easily-build-your-own-linux-distro)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't think I would get one so quickly, especially with all of the people saying it's too broad.

Comment: Re *"all of the people saying..."*: see [*CIII. THE ART OF DISCOURAGEMENT.*](https://archive.org/details/mcguffeysfifthec00mcgu_1/page/308)

Comment: I just got to looking at those links. I didn't look at LFS yet, though. I meant customize the dock or taskbar to look just right and design the border around open windows. I would also like to create my own menu, like the windows start menu.