# Total Commander "compare content" like alternative?

Tags: diff

I'm searching a GUI [or CLI] tool that can produce output like the Total Commander compare content function does! For example:

[image: Screenshot of Total Commander]

Are there any that do that? It's a very handy tool and I miss it

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/which-gui-diff-viewer-would-you-recommend

Comment: Are you just looking for any diff tool, or is there something specific about that screenshot you want?

Comment: The imageshack domain is blocked here. Perhaps use SE's 'native' image site, imgur.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- xxdiff
- gtkdiff
- tkdiff

come to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

`diff -y`?

Or if what you're really after is **color** output try [colordiff](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Any diff utility can do this for you.  My personal favorite GUI tool is [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/).

If you like the command line, but want a paged side-by-side comparison, try:

`diff -y | less`

Answer (score 0):

I like [Meld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meld_(software)). (See also its [Github repository](https://github.com/GNOME/meld)).

On Debian and derived systems, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install meld
```

There are also MacOS and even Windows versions available.

On MacOS, it can be installed with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), or using "[a fork of Meld packaged and bundled for OSX](https://yousseb.github.io/meld/this%20port)".