# Is there a way to merge two files smartly?

Tags: files, merge

I have two files with some lines being the same.

File A :

```
command 1{
    some code lines
}
command 2
command 3
command 4{
    some code lines
}
```

File B :

```
command 5
command 3
command 1{
    some code lines
}
```

I'd like to have a final file containing this:

```
command 1{
    some code lines
}
command 2
command 3
command 4{
    some code lines
}
command 5
```

Order of lines is not relevant. Is there an existing tool (or a command) to do so?

Comment: Not a single command that I remember, but you can do it trivially by combining sort and uniq.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/which-gui-diff-viewer-would-you-recommend/4594#4594

Answer (score 1):

I realized this should be a <s>comment</s> answer.

I don't remember if there is a single tool that will do that. **But**! You can achieve the exact effect by cat'ing the files and then using `sort` and `uniq` to do the job:

```
cat A B | sort | uniq
```

This throws the contents of both files together, then sorts the lines and removes any duplicates.

Resulting output:

```
command 1
command 2
command 3
command 4
command 5
```

Comment: The trouble is, I can't use `sort` on files. I updated my example to be more precise. Not sorting makes `uniq` useless, and sorting makes my file useless :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool to my knowledge that will merge the files in the way that you've shown. Most of the merging/diffing tools work by having some level of context around the various lines so that the tool knows 2 files can go together in various places throughout.

What you're showing doesn't have any real context so I don't see how these tools would be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
sed -e 's/_/_u/g;s/%/_p/g;/{$/s/^/%/;/{$/,/}$/b' -e 's/^/%/' A B |
  tr '%\n' '\n%' |
  sort -u |
  tr '%\n' '\n%' |
  sed 's/%//g;s/_p/%/g;s/_u/_/g'
```

If the files don't contain the `%` character, you can simplify it to:

```
sed -e '/{$/s/^/%/;/{$/,/}$/b' -e 's/^/%/' A B |
  tr '%\n' '\n%' |
  sort -u |
  tr -d '\n' |
  tr % '\n'
```