# Activating WiFi in Fedora

Tags: fedora, wifi

I am using a Fedora 13 OS and i see that in the network connections the WiFi thing has been disabled. Generally when there is a WiFi connection around it would show in the Wireless networks option, but it is not showing for me. What to do, in order to keep the WiFi mode always active.

**ADDED**

I have tried the following

```
iwlist wlan0 power
```

It says the mode is off.

`ifconfig wlan0` gives me the following output:

> wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:19:7D3:0C:FD
>   UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
>   RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>   TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>   collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>   RX bytes:0 (0.0 b) TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

`iwconfig` has the following:

> wlan0 IEEE 802.11bg Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated
>   Tx-Power=20 dBm
>   Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
>   Power Management:off

Comment: You got your physical laptop wifi button switched on? You have the right firmware installed? (optional) You got a screenshot?

Comment: @chrandu1, please clarify "wifi thing". And like Tshepang mentioned, ensure that your wifi switch is set to 'on'.

Comment: @Stefan: i have my wifi button on, but still when i have wired network it gets connected, but when there is a wifi network it doesnt show the connections at all. How do i search for a wifi connection if i know that i am in an area with wifi conectivity

Comment: running this `iwlist wlan0 scanning` as [root](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063) should show you a list of found devices... also see `man iwlist` and `iwlist --help`

Comment: @Stefan: it says interface doesnt support scanning network is down

Comment: @stefan: And suppose i get a connection A, how do i activate that wireless connection

Comment: @stefan: iwlist wlan0 power it says wlan mode: off please tell me how to turn it on

Comment: @chandru... ur asking me a lot of question I just don't have answers to :(

Answer (score 1):

Why do you bother with weird `iwconfig` commands. Have you used "`nm-applet`" command? This is a GNOME Network Management applet. I tried to manage wireless connections with iwconfig on my Fedora's laptop but gave up. nm-applet does all the job you need. Just select auto-connect option for your wireless connection and it will connect you each time wifi is up.

I use this applet in PekWM window manager with bmpanel application. This is because Pekwm does not have panel itself.