# Light-weight alternative to Apache

Tags: webserver, file-sharing

In my set-up, I run ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)) `ln -s ~/share /var/www`. By doing this, anyone on the local network will access the *~/share* directory by pointing their browsers at http://hostname/share. I use `apache`, but I suspect that it's overkill (memory usage) for this simple use.

What alternative light-weight web servers can I use for this? Will it also be tinker-free (in Debian, there's no extra set-up for `apache`, beyond installation)?

Comment: how little memory do you have? I suspect with the next to no use the server will receive, it doesn't really matter how light/heavy?

Comment: I'm not even running short, but then again, I don't burn money just because I'm a billionaire. Also, I do think it matters, because it's likely that the bigger the httpd, the longer it takes to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have a long list for this. At my workplace we have [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) instead of Apache. Cherokee has a nice web admin interface that makes configuration really easy.

I also heard about [Nginx](http://www.nginx.org/) and [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/).

Comment: Cherokee looks good. I also like how it displays the icons.

Answer (score 3):

[Lighthttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) is lightweight and easy to setup.  nginx seems to be the more popular choice nowadays, tho.

It really isn't going to make much of a difference either way.  I'd just stick with Apache, if you want to tweak it to use less memory try apache2-mpm-worker.

```
sudo aptitude install apache2-mpm-worker
```

Also, since you want all this stuff working 'out of the box', what version Debian are you running?

Comment: I use Debian Squeeze. Also, I just install `apache2` which installs whatever `apache2-mpm-worker` installs, and nothing more.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Apache2 uses mpm_prefork by default which is single threaded and so uses more memory.

Comment: In Debian, **apache2** is a meta-package that depends on **apache2-mpm-worker** or **apache2-mpm-prefork** or **apache2-mpm-event** or **apache2-mpm-itk**, in that order. That is, running `apt-get install apache2` will pull in **apache2-mpm-worker**, and if it's not available, will go on to the next one, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/).  It's very lightweight, uses very few resources.  It does have some slightly odd policies about file access as I recall.

Comment: requires some tinkering --> didn't work out-of-the-box

Answer (score 2):

[nginx](http://nginx.org/) (pronounced Engine-X) is a very popular lightweight alternative for serving static (and other) content.  It works out of the box on most distributions.

Comment: requires some tinkering --> didn't work out-of-the-box

Answer (score 0):

for temporary share, I have this shell script in my path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PORT=${1:-8000}
DIR=${2:-\.}

cd "$DIR"
python -c "import SimpleHTTPServer;SimpleHTTPServer.test()" $PORT
```

By default, shares the current directory on port 8000, syntax is `scriptname [<port> [<dir>]]`

Comment: I can't help wondering, will the Python module SimpleHTTPServer allow concurrent file sharing? Last time I checked it didn't seem to.

Comment: @phunehehe if you want concurrency, try [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455606/basichttpserver-simplehttpserver-and-concurrency) but if you go so far, keep apache, add mod_userdir, even like that it will be lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Debian packages that provide a web server [provide](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual) the `httpd` package. Just about anything in there that isn't a version of Apache is a lightweight web server.

Comment: I went through that list, and it was what-a-waste-of-time (some of the stuff is hardly maintained, some isn't tinker-free), that's why I asked for specific recommendations.