# Using live-helper offline

Tags: debian, livecd

I'm trying to create a custom Debian liveCD using live-helper, but offline. It was more or less possible with apt-cdrom  (using the official DVDs to solve all the dependencies).

I did `lh config` and then `lh build`, like I'm supposed to. Problem is it failed and gave me this error:

```
E: Failed getting release file: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/Release
```

I poked around the internet and found an option about `--mirror-bootstrap` and using it to redirect to *http://localhost/debian*, but it gives the same error. I even tried fetching the *Release* file and using a local path (eg `/root/debian/dists/squeeze/Release`), but it wouldn't recognize it. I seem to need to use a URL, but I can't use a url to redirect to local hard drive.

I did find this though: http://lists.debian.org/debian-live/2007/07/msg00152.html
I didn't find any solution there, but it's the most information I could find.

I can't connect that computer to the internet, what can I do??

Comment: Are you running a web server?

Comment: nope. Just basic Debian, not even with a GUI.

Comment: Run a web server (I recommend [cherokee](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5594/688)... for your purpose, it won't need any setup), add a link to your local repository (`sudo ln -s /root/debian /var/www`), and try again.

Comment: the hell? why does it have to be so complicated?

Comment: It's just two steps... install a web server and tell it where your repository is located.

Comment: Trying this solution, I got stuck while trying to download *ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dist/squeeze* . No matter what I try with wget, I only get the index.html file. Any ideas? There are more files that Release required.

Comment: I forgot to mention that with the web server, your APT entry will be `deb http://localhost/debian squeeze main` or somesuch.

Comment: Without the web server, you can have this in your APT source entry, `deb file://root/debian squeeze main`.

Comment: why can't it just use the `apt-cdrom` source? How do I get an offline repository then? How is that any different from the release-DVDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These instructions assume that you want to create a live disc from just one Debian DVD (or CD). I don't know how to combine different CD/DVD images to be one repository.

1. Install a web server:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cherokee
   ```
2. Create a mount point on the web server path and mount the disc:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /var/www/squeeze
   sudo mount /dev/scd0 /var/www/squeeze
   ```
3. Create a directory which will contain the configs and the live disc and navigate to it:

   ```
   mkdir /path/to/live-build-dir
   cd /path/to/live-build-dir
   ```
4. Run **`live-build`** config generator:

   ```
   lb config --mirror-bootstrap http://localhost/squeeze
   ```

   Look at **`lb_config`** manpage for a myriad other options. Also, ensure to wipe out your config directories if you re-run `lb config` command. Look at the docs for an explanation.
5. Build the live disc:

   ```
   sudo lb build
   ```

**NOTES**:

- I've tried with direct file access (`file:/path/to/apt-repository`), and it doesn't work. Probably a bug.
- If you want to build Squeeze images, use the Squeeze version of live-build. The version in Wheezy or Unstable is currently broken, and the developers discourage it's usage, other than for testing. The config formats are not even compatible.

Comment: I'm going in this direction, I got *cherokee* working and files there seem to work. How do I get a local repository? I'm not 100% sure what does it mean, can you explain in a sentence? (like, do I run `apt-local get_repository` or something?) I got a local repository in the form of the installation DVD, and someone mentioned I can mount them to `/var/www/`, how do I do that? (just `mount /dev/hdc /var/www apt-repository`?)

Comment: I added the info addressing your question on the Answer.

Comment: It failed on "installing base packages", specifically isc-dhcp-common. bah. What now?

Comment: Can you update your post with the exact error message as well as the exact disc (e.g. Debian 6.0.1 disc1).

Comment: Debian stable 6.0.0 DVD1. Error message: `W: Failure while installing base packages. This will be re-attempted up to five times`, and this happened just after `I: Upacking isc-dhcp-common`, and also last time it failed on that. I'm downloading 6.0.1a and I'll try that, but I doubt that will make a change.

Comment: How did it go? What/when is *last time*?

Comment: what do you mean? it tried five times (to unpack `isc-dhcp-common`, I guess), and failed.

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: Did 6.0.1a work?

Comment: bugger, not even 6.0.1a

Comment: Give me some time so I can try reproduce your problem.

Comment: I get stuck even earlier than you: `E: Failed getting release signature file... Release.gpg`. This happens very early on. How did you get past it?

Comment: you probably misspelled the localhost url, try `wget`ing it. Make sure it's where **live-helper** is expecting it.

Comment: @user: I didn't because it could get the Release file.

Comment: huh, I see, odd. Try adding the disc to sources.list file by using `apt-cdrom add` when the disc is in the tray. If all goes well, I think the `...localhost/...` URL is wrong. Check the default url..?

Comment: anything..? Why is this so complex? The problem is said to be in debootstrap, can I file a bug over there..?

Comment: I strongly suspect that running `debootstrap` with `--no-check-gpg` option would solve the issue.

Comment: @user: sorry I missed this message. My point was that if it could check for Release file, then there's nothing wrong with my url settings. Anyways, how would adding cdrom as source help?

Comment: if debootstrap would use the source.list file.. then all is well, as all the packages are there. The Apt system is so great because it has all the tools developed over time, and not some self written hack to read an online repository...