# installing ffmpeg-php on centos

Tags: linux, centos, ffmpeg, php

With the help of [this guide](http://forum.syslint.com/topic/136/solved-install-ffmpegphp-061-along-with-ffmpeginstaller-63/), I am trying to install ffmpeg using these commands:

```
 # cd ffmpeg-php/branches/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php-0.6.1/
 # replace 'PIX_FMT_RGBA32' 'PIX_FMT_RGB32' -- *
 # phpize 
 # ./configure --with-ffmpeg=/usr/local/cpffmpeg
 # make 
 # make install
```

But when I run this `replace 'PIX_FMT_RGBA32' 'PIX_FMT_RGB32' -- *` I get this error:

> replace: Error reading file
>   'autom4te.cache' (Errcode: 21)
>   replace: Error reading file 'build'
>   (Errcode: 21) ffmpeg_frame.c converted
>   replace: Error reading file 'include'
>   (Errcode: 21) replace: Error reading
>   file 'modules' (Errcode: 21) replace:
>   Error reading file 'tests' (Errcode:
>   21)

And when I run `make` and skip that line I get:

```
/root/ffmpeg-php/branches/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php-0.6.1/ffmpeg-php.c:171: error: expected '{' at end of input
make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Curiously, did you do all of that as root? I say that because `#` normally implies that the command is ran [as root](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root).

Answer (score 1):

The errors from `replace` are harmless, it's just telling you (cryptically) that these files are directories and it can't act on them.

But you do need to run `phpize` and `./configure …` before you can run `make`.

Comment: yes i am running them before i run make..

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you would need to edit the only one file i.e. ffmpeg_frame.c

```
replace 'PIX_FMT_RGBA32' 'PIX_FMT_RGB32' -- ffmpeg_frame.c
./configure
make
make install
```

This should install ffmpeg-php on the server - you will need to add the ffmpeg.so file to your php.ini file like:

```
extension=ffmpeg.so
```

Restart Apache on the server once the extension is added.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `yum`?

On Ubuntu doing `aptitude install php5-ffmpeg` seems to automatically install `ffmpeg` and all it's dependencies. Perhaps [the same package is available for CentOS](http://www.google.com/search?q=yum+install+php5-ffmpeg)?