# No output produced when using winFF

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am using [winFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) in Ubuntu 10.04. WinFF is a graphical frontend to ffmpeg.

Typically, after selecting a file in WinFF, setting my conversion settings and pressing the "Convert" button, a console appears with output from the conversion process and prompts requesting permission to continue.

However, now, when I press convert,  I only see a blank console with a command prompt such as:

```
oneat@oneat-desktop:~$
```

I thought I had misconfigured something, but I reinstalled everything but problem continues. Could you help me ?

In general console output still works, since I see output when I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "\033]0; Converting _quot;LIKE A G6_quot; (OFFICIAL) FAR EAST MOVEMENT (FM) feat (1/1)\007"
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "/home/oneat/dwhelper/_quot;LIKE A G6_quot; (OFFICIAL) FAR EAST MOVEMENT (FM) feat.flv" -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec msmpeg4 -ab 192kb -b 1000kb -s 640x480 -ar 44100 "/home/oneat/_quot;LIKE A G6_quot; (OFFICIAL) FAR EAST MOVEMENT (FM) feat.avi"
read -p "Press Enter to Continue" dumbyvar
rm "/home/oneat/.winff/ff110111193250.sh"
```

Comment: Maybe, but not with the little information you've posted. You need to describe precisely what you're doing: where did you get the program (FFGUI?), on what OS (Ubuntu, but what version), how do you start it (click on a menu entry? command in a terminal?), what happens exactly? Be precise enough so that someone can reproduce what you're doing on their machine.

Comment: paste the whole shell command you use for it please.

Comment: Is `_quot;LIKE A G6_quot;` actually part of the file name or was this some copy and pasting error?  Also, are you saying that this series of commands work when you type them in but not when you run your script using something like `$ ./myscript.sh`?

Comment: FFMPEG just doesn't print anything! It's good with code! There is just problem that gui doesn't print commands to SHELL!!

Comment: @oneat: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you're trying to do and where things don't work the way you want. Again, the best way to get people to understand your question would be to describe what you're doing *very precisely*, with enough information so that people could try it on their machine.

Comment: @oneat, I heavily edited your question.  Please make sure it accurately reflects your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about this software, but after quickly installing it, I get the impression it was not well packaged.

You said that you tried reinstalling the package; however, when you reinstalled it, did you also remove its configuration files?  By default in Debian, Ubuntu, and other distributions, configuration files are left behind in case you reinstall again.  I would try something like the following([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)):

```
# apt-get purge winff
# apt-get update
# apt-get install winff
```

From the `apt-get` manual page:

> purge
>
> purge is identical to remove except
>   that packages are removed and purged
>   (any configuration files are deleted
>   too).

Comment: I did it. It didn't work. I even reinstalled ffdshow and now inserting these commands directly to cmd  works. But Winff still can't pass them there.Any possibilities why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Solution (not nice though):

1. Go on Options and Select Display CMD Line
2. Click on Convert:

   - A terminal appears with commands
   - Copy the contents of the window, save it in a file
   - Run at as a shell script (sh filename)