# How to get lilbmp3lame encoding to work with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

When I am converting an FLV to an AVI one, I always get:

```
Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
```

But I've installed it with Ubuntu Software Center.

I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec msmpeg4 -ab 192kb -b 1000kb -s 640x480 -ar 44100 video.avi
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Run ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)) `apt-get install libavcodec-extra-52`. If that doesn't work, ensure that you have **multiverse** enabled, do `apt-get update` and try again.

[**note**] This is for Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick). See if you can find a similarly-named package if you use a different Ubuntu release, by running `aptitude search liavcodec-extra`.