# How do I suppress dd output?

Tags: bash, sudo, su, dd

I have a bash script that creates some file using `dd`. The problem is dd throws a great amount of output that is going to mess with the output of my script.
Searching around I've found a solution:

```
dd if=boot1h of="/dev/r$temp1" >& /dev/null
```

Is there an alternative, or is redirecting to `/dev/null` the only way?

Comment: I'm lost on your last sentence, "the script should not request for privileges". That doesn't seem to have anything to do with redirecting to `/dev/null` -- you're sudoing because `dd` needs write access to `/dev/r$temp1` (I assume). You're going to need to do that no matter how you suppress `dd`'s output; redirecting output to `/dev/null` doesn't require root

Comment: I'm an idiot. It was giving operation not permitted because of the use of /dev/r$temp1/. I'm really sorry. I'm editing a script that's not mine and didn't noticed it. Really sorry.

Comment: so the problem is regular user cannot write to /dev/r$temp1 or to dev/null

Comment: Don't worry about it; I edited it a bit to remove the confusing part

Comment: If you're not using any of dd's advanced features, use `cat`, `head` or `tail` instead.

Comment: Please consider marking the post by @orgoj as the answer instead, since it has been a decent few years and dd 8.21 is likely on almost everyones machines at this point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the `dd(1)` man page:

```
   status=noxfer
          suppress transfer statistics
```

thus:

```
dd if=boot1h of="/dev/r$temp1" status=noxfer
```

This still outputs the

```
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
```

garbage when `dd` exits, so redirecting to a data sink really is your only option.

Comment: that was I'm afraid of.

Comment: I believe status=noxfer, could be related to SIGUSR1 signal, that normally show the transfer statistic. Hoewever, I am not willing to test if it's true what I am saying.

Answer (score 89):

Add `status=none`:

```
dd if=boot1h of="/dev/r$temp1" status=none
```

From the [dd (coreutils) 8.21 docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html#dd-invocation):

> ```
> 'status=LEVEL'
>      Transfer information is normally output to stderr upon receipt of
>      the 'INFO' signal or when 'dd' exits.  Specifying LEVEL will adjust
>      the amount of information printed, with the last LEVEL specified
>      taking precedence.
>
>      'none'
>           Do not print any informational or warning messages to stderr.
>           Error messages are output as normal.
>
>      'noxfer'
>           Do not print the final transfer rate and volume statistics
>           that normally make up the last status line.
>
>      'progress'
>           Print the transfer rate and volume statistics on stderr, when
>           processing each input block.  Statistics are output on a
>           single line at most once every second, but updates can be
>           delayed when waiting on I/O.
> ```

Comment: @roaima - just curious, why editing a quote from the man page ?

Comment: @don_crissti I felt the (lack of) context in extracting the quote from the man page mean that it required a slightly different form of words. As it stands in the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html#dd-invocation) it's fine; here it looked strange.

Comment: @roaima -  all right - curiosity satisfied :) - but note that you link to the `info page`; the initial answer here had the _exact quote_ from the [`man page`](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=DD&ampsect=1). I would have copy/pasted directly from the `info` page if the `man` page is ambiguous but really, up to you... Oh, btw, thanks much for your other comment on my answer related to sorting by week day.

Comment: @don_crissti I couldn't find a man page online that had the quote; thank you for that one. (die.net has the older `dd` without `status=`)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be available in dd (coreutils) 8.13:

```dd: invalid status flag: `none'
Try `dd --help' for more information.```

Comment: Neither the `status=none` option, nor redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`, nor redirecting stderr to stdout with `2>&1` and then redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`, makes a difference for the dd output on my machine (Debian Stretch).

Comment: is `status=none` supported by busybox? how about toybox? how about OpenBSD/FreeBSD? how about Solaris? i know that support for `status=progress` varies wildly

Answer (score 6):

For future reference:

To suppress dd output completely redirect stderr to /dev/null like so:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=5MB count=1 2> /dev/null
```

This works nicely if you want to, for example, time the process using the time command in bash and assign the result to a variable, without getting any of the output that dd produces.

reference: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/131624-how-suppress-dd-output.html

Answer (score 3):

With any Unix application or command, you can suppress all output with

`cmd >/dev/null 2>&1`

The first bit redirects the standard output (unit number 1) to /dev/null. But you need the second part to ALSO redirect the error output (unit number 2) to the same place as number 1.

In UNIX, STDIN=0, STDOUT=1 and STDERR=2

---

Comment: Actually, `stderr` has the file descriptor **2**. (I assume "STDERR=3" is just a typo.)

Comment: It is undesirable to suppress all output.  If an error occurs, we would like to see the error message.

Comment: `cmd 2>logfile.txt` seems more adapted

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should also work for you with recent versions of BASH and ZSH:

```
dd if=/path/to/file of=/path/to/another_file bs=1M count=1 &> /dev/null
```

P.S. This is just an example I ran...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, are you putting that `sudo` command into the script and expecting the script to prompt for your password when it runs there? In that case you are just doing things the complicated way.

A cleaner solution is to write the script in the usual way (i.e without `sudo`) and [run it as the superuser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/250). The reason behind this is, if the script needs superuser access, then just give it the access (why wait until a certain command?). In the script, to check if it is being run as root do something like this:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: nope. That's exactly what I don't want to do. I don't want the script to be run as root only because I don't want dd to display the output. Your check would correct if I want the script to be run as superuser.

Comment: @dierre So why did you need `sudo` in the first place? Normal users should be able to redirect things to `/dev/null` just fine.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and it's giving me operation not permitted...uhm...

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't notice I was creating something under /dev/. The script is not mine, I was editing it. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect the output to an regular file i.e.:

```
 dd if=boot1h of="/dev/r$temp1" >& /tmp/dd.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the man page, using `dd status=none` won't get rid of error messages.

If there is a single error message that is expected/desirable, you can use `grep` to both check that execution was as expected and eat the output. In this example, I obliterate a partition by overwriting with zeros so that `mke2fs` won't question the need to reformat it.

Running `dd` without a `count` specifier will always result in a "No space left on device" error message and nonzero exit value. By searching for the expected error message with `grep`, the expected behavior returns no error while any unexpected behavior returns an error.

```
# desired behavior: erase to the end of partition and return zero as exit code.
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk2p7 bs=1M 2>&1 | grep -q 'No space left on device'
$ echo $?
0

# Nonzero exit code is returned if our expected error message doesn't appear. 
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk2p7 bs=1M 2>&1 | grep -q 'Frobulators are not block-aligned'
$ echo $?
1
```

The redirect of `stderr` to `stdout` is necessary because most `dd` output goes to `stderr` while `grep` operates on `stdout`. Use grep's `-q` flag to control visibility of the output.