# How to find out which Wi-Fi driver is installed?

Tags: linux, drivers, wifi

I know about `lsmod`, but how do I figure out which driver does what?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$ readlink /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/ath5k
```

In other words, the `/sys` hierarchy for the device (`/sys/class/net/$interface/device`) contains a symbolic link to the `/sys` hierarchy for the driver. There you'll also find a symbolic link to the `/sys` hierarchy for the module, if applicable. This applies to most devices, not just wireless interfaces.

Comment: Or `basename $( readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver )`.

Answer (score 26):

Maybe there's a better way, but I've used `lshw -class network` ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/)) and it gives me this output:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:a0:d1:a3:87:c8
       size: 1GB/s
       capacity: 1GB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.0.2-k2 duplex=full firmware=0.3-0 ip=192.168.2.206 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1GB/s
       resources: irq:29 memory:fc300000-fc31ffff memory:fc325000-fc325fff ioport:1840(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 61
       serial: 00:1d:e0:69:28:07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:31 memory:c8000000-c8001fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: vboxnet0
       serial: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes multicast=yes
```

You can grep for `driver` from that output. In my case I use `lsmod | grep iwlagn`, giving me:

```
iwlagn                 63559  0 
iwlcore                67702  1 iwlagn
mac80211              123574  2 iwlagn,iwlcore
cfg80211               87657  3 iwlagn,iwlcore,mac80211
```

Don't ask me what each of those mean :)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried using `lshw`, but the driver was lost within all the other configuration. :)

Comment: PS, the 4th column is the dependencies column and 3rd column is the sum of these dependencies. One driver typically consists of several different .ko files, each of which has a corresponding in `lsmod`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in USB based WiFi devices then you can see the driver name by using the `lsusb` command:

```
lsusb -t
```