# How do I create a new file and edit it as root?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, gedit

I've tried: `gksudo gedit /etc/xinetd.d/tftp` (this is the path I need). I got an error message:

```
couldn't find the file /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
please check that you typed the location correctly and try again
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

My version of gedit (2.22.3) does create the file if it doesn't exist. If yours doesn't, you can create the file first with `sudo touch /etc/xinetd.d/tftp`.

I recommend using `sudoedit /etc/xinetd.d/tftp` instead. This uses your favorite editor, taken from the `EDITOR` [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), or a system default if you haven't expressed your preference. Add `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/gedit` to your `~/.profile` if necessary.

See also [How do I run a command as the system administrator (root)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root).

Answer (score 0):

I made a new launcher for my desktop (I installed gnome desktop fallback)
by gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop.
then typed in as the run command: gksu nautilus
that runs as root.

navigated to my regular home that logs in show hidden files went inside Templates folder, made new file and newfile.php and newfile.html
I also edited those files and put in my code I usually create with.

then I copied the Templates file and navigated to "root' home the paste it there (the folder is missing) now when I run nautilus as root I can create my files as well as the untittled with no extention. then edit with gedit using the nautilus I launched as root with my new launcher (gksu nautilus)

Ubuntu 14.01LTS