# Wireless in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, wifi

I am trying to get wireless working a lenovo g560. I tried following the instructions on the debian site here http://wiki.debian.org/wl but it is not working. At step 7 I get an error that modprobe does not exist. Anybody know of a straightforward tutorial or got any tips?

Comment: Are you running the command [as root](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063)?

Answer (score 1):

`/sbin` is not part of your `PATH` and thats why its complaining. So try `/sbin/modprobe`.

Comment: @thesteve: If `/sbin` is not in your `PATH`, it's because you're doing something wrong. The commands should be run as root, and any reasonable method to become root will add `/sbin` to the `PATH`.