# How to add an iso file as APT source

Tags: mount, apt

Say I have this line in "**/etc/fstab**":

```
/iso/apt.iso /mnt/apt iso9660 loop 0 0
```

And I run these commands [as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/688):

```
mount --all
apt-cdrom add --no-mount --cdrom /mnt/apt
```

I expected the disk to be added as APT source, but nothing happens. What's missing?

**UPDATE**:

I followed [this advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8822/how-to-add-an-iso-file-as-apt-source/8844#8844) and now I'm getting this:

```
Using CD-ROM mount point /media/cdrom/
Identifying.. [61c5dd7c11a32dc999e655c235cd698e-2]
Scanning disc for index files..
Found 0 package indexes, 0 source indexes, 0 translation indexes and 0 signatures
W: Failed to mount '/dev/sr0' to '/media/cdrom/'
E: Unable to locate any package files, perhaps this is not a Debian Disc or the wrong architecture?
```

This happens with or without "**/etc/apt/apt.conf**" changes.

Comment: Did you run `mount /mnt/apt` before `apt-cdrom -m -d=/mnt/apt add`?

Comment: @forcefsck: I used `mount --all` before the `apt-cdrom` cmd.

Answer (score 6):

here's what worked for me:

first, the line in `/etc/fstab` should look like this:

```
/iso/apt.iso /mnt/apt iso9660 user,loop 0 0
```

then, with the mount-point mounted, run `apt-cdrom` like this:

```
apt-cdrom -m -d=/mnt/apt add
```

if apt still asks you to insert the disk, add these lines to apt.conf

```
Acquire::cdrom::mount "/mnt/apt";
APT::CDROM::NoMount;
```

I think you should find this will work for you too :)