# How do you change the root password on Debian?

Tags: debian, root, password

I want to change the password I assigned to root on my Debian webserver to something longer and more secure.

How do I do that? I haven’t forgotten/lost the current password, I just want to change it.

Comment: To find this out for yourself, run `apropos password`: you'll get a list of commands that contain “password” in their short description. You can narrow the search a little with `apropos -s 1 password`: `-s 1` restricts to section 1 of the manual, which contains user commands.

Comment: @Gilles: that’s fantastic, I had no idea.

Comment: Have you considered, instead, `sudo`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Ah, [use the `passwd` program](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/change-my-root-password-in-debian-linux-if-i-have-the-current-password-693323/) [as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/250):

```
sudo passwd root
```

Or, if you’re running as root already (which you shouldn’t be), just:

```
passwd
```

The `root` argument can be omitted, because when you execute `passwd` it defaults to the current user (which is root, as only root can change the root password).

Comment: Obvious in hindsight, really. :)

Comment: @Shadur: *painfully* :) I’d just never done it before, and the Google links I found first were for folks who had forgotten the root password.

Comment: Should be `sudo passwd`, or just plain `passwd` if you are running with root privileges.

Comment: @phunehehe: ah, gotcha. Answer edited; do I need `root` after `sudo passwd` if I’m not running as root?

Comment: @Paul I took liberty in editing your answer. There are a few ways to run things as root, and when `passwd` is run as root, it defaults to modify the `root` user.

Comment: @phunehehe: excellent, much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe should say su -c 'passwd root' for systems like CentOS, Fedora, RHEL where sudo isn't installed. This would help teach newbies not to run as root by default.

Comment: Did you ask this to get self-rep... it's on the first page of google results!

Comment: @jamespo: no. When I Googled initially, I only noticed links saying how to reset a lost root password. I do tend to ask on SE sites quite quickly, but only to make the answer easy for me to find in the future.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's worked, but when i'm going to login via Ctrl+Alt+F1 , it's says incorrect login!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: rough spot.

Comment: @Katerberg You can just use su -c "passwd"

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be doing a lot of command-line administration, you might find it useful to check out the man pages for usermod(8), chfn(1), chsh(1), passwd(1), crypt(3), gpasswd(8), groupadd(8),

Answer (score -2):

You have to boot in Recovery Mode before using Paul D. Waite's suggestion:

1. Right after booting your Debian system choose "boot in Recovery Mode"
2. Right after booting into "Recovery Mode" right at the command prompt simply 
   type:

   ```
   sudo password root
   ```

   then the system will ask for the new Root's password once and twice to verify and you ARE done.

Comment: “You have to boot in Recovery Mode before using Paul D. Waite's suggestion” — Really? I don’t remember doing that. Is this a new thing in a new version of Debian?