# How can I install MS Windows fonts on Fedora 15?

Tags: fedora, fonts

I've just installed Fedora 15 and here is some troubles with fonts. How can I install MS fonts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is slightly modified from the instructions found [here](http://www.fedorafaq.org/#installfonts) (and I haven't even checked if they work):

1. Install the [chkfontpath package](http://atrpms.net/dist/f14/chkfontpath/) from ATrpms (Click on either the i686 or x86_64 package, depending on whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit machine).
2. [As root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/688), install some packages you'll need for the following steps:

   ```
   yum install rpm-build cabextract ttmkfdir wget
   ```
3. Download the MS Core Fonts Smart Package File:

   ```
   wget http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/msttcorefonts-2.0-1.spec
   ```
4. Build the Core Fonts package:

   ```
   rpmbuild -ba msttcorefonts-2.0-1.spec
   ```
5. Install the Core Fonts package:

   ```
   yum install --nogpgcheck /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/msttcorefonts-2.0-1.noarch.rpm
   ```

Comment: RPM building shouldn't be done as root, in general. The only parts of this that need to be done as root are the `yum` operations. And building a random, unreviewed specfile as root _or_ non-root is somewhat dangerous.

Comment: And not necessarily more importantly from an overall standpoint, but definitely from a practical one, chkfontpath as used in this specfile is [no longer in Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Deprecated_packages), so this won't work without modification.

Comment: @mattdm: I didn't mean for `wget` and `rpmbuild` to be run as root.

Comment: @mattdm: can you edit the question. It was merely a copy-paste... I don't really know the details.

Comment: I had to comment lines 19, 20, 21 and 22 because when you run the rpmbuild error was obsolete instructions

Answer (score 5):

With the modern font libraries, this is easy. The best way is to simply get the `.ttf` files you want and drop them into `~/.fonts` in your home directory. (If that doesn't exist, create it.)

Then, they should be available to your applications. This is per-user rather than system-wide (which you get with the `msttcorefonts` package), but has some advantages — you don't have to build an RPM, for one, and second, if you preserve your home directory when you upgrade to Fedora 16, they'll still be there and still just work.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with [Tshepang's method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13720/windows-fonts-on-fedora-15/13723#13723), but this worked for me ([source](http://nosnahoi.blogspot.com/2011/04/windows-fonts-in-fedora-15-betahow-to.html)):

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://fedora.missingbox.co.nz/core-fonts.rpm
yum localinstall --nogpgcheck core-fonts.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use mjmwired's msttcorefonts package or atleast his SPEC to build it yourself.
http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-f15.html#ttf

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
rpm -i https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.2-1.noarch.rpm
```

This RPM installs the fonts from SourceForge at install time, it does not contain the fonts.  In addition, it pulls in updated fonts from the EUupdate font set, and installs the fonts correctly to X core and Xft.

Answer (score 1):

You need also rpmdevtools to build rpm.

su -c "yum install rpmdevtools rpm-build cabextract ttmkfdir"

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=273302

Answer (score 0):

```
yum -y localinstall http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm && yum -y update --nogpgcheck && yum -y install freetype-freeworld wget cabextract fontconfig xorg-x11-font-utils && wget http://repo.missingbox.co.nz/repo/linux/msfonts/1.2/msfontinstaller.sh && sh msfontinstaller.sh
```

Comment: Do explain a little bit about the whole command.