# MS Core Fonts download?

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for the MS core fonts. I can't find any good Linux downloads. All I can find are Windows installers; you have to download one for each font, then go through a huge process to get everything extracted.
I'm running Puppy Linux. This means that I can't just open the EXE's as archives.

I don't care whether the download is .tar.gz, .zip, .rar, .tc, or even .torrent; I just want the fonts.

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13720/how-can-i-install-ms-windows-fonts-on-fedora-15); that one is specifically about installation on Fedora, likewise, the answers are about as Fedora-specific as humanly possible. They would all be entirely inapplicable to any other non-redhat-based Linux distro.

I have a strong suspicion that this question doesn't quite belong on this site, so could whoever closes it leave a comment explaining which site this belongs on (or, even better, migrate it?) I couldn't find any site that fit my question more perfectly than this one...

Answer (score 2):

this is where my gentoo gets it from if i install from the repo: http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That one just offers a bunch of exe installers. After downloading them all, I'd have to reboot to Ubuntu, and extract the ttf's from them each one-by-one with File Roller. I'm looking for something a lot less painfully tedious. I'm on Puppy Linux, so I don't have any "sissy package managers" to help me out.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - the problem is with Microsoft's EULA - it doesn't allow redistributing the fonts in a changed form. By doing this folks would be violating the license. BTW, what's wrong with installing `cabextract`?

Comment: The key thing here is that the exe files are really a self-extracting cab archives. So those files plus `cabextract` and there you are. And, cabextract for Puppy Linux seems easy: http://puppylinux.org/wikka/cabextract

Comment: @mattdm Aha, I didn't realize it was that easy to get cabextract on Puppy. Thanks. :)

Comment: @DeerHunter I didn't realize it was that easy to install cabextract. Also, I am fully aware of the legal implications of straight-up downloading it, which is why I mentioned .torrent as an option. ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you're really asking for is a script that will download the fonts, extract them, and install them for you...

Here is what Ubuntu uses: 
[ttf-mscorefonts-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Comment: The distro of Puppy I'm using doesn't support debian packages. Unless it has a built-in cabextract (that's binarily compatible with Slackware,) that package is useless to me.

Comment: Best way to install deb package in slackware:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/best-way-to-install-deb-package-in-slackware-907732/

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Web Fonts are available for download in a .tar.gz from https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/.

Comment: Instructions for installing them from there into a typical Ubuntu Linux system: https://askubuntu.com/a/1092920