# How to find out ip of local-link-ed linux? (make one discoverable by ip, broadcast, discovery, avahi)

Tags: linux, networking, ip, avahi

I connected two Linux PCs with local-link directly. I now want one to know e.g. ipv6 address assigned by local-link connection. I've tried web search for discover and make discoverable, etc. and found a number of QAs, https://askubuntu.com/questions/947639/how-to-find-the-ip-address-for-a-device-on-a-network, [How to make a machine accessible from the LAN using its hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname), https://serverfault.com/questions/1036362/how-to-nicely-make-a-neighbors-discovery-solicitation-on-linux, [How can I make my linux machine broadcast its IP address dynamically?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302331/how-can-i-make-my-linux-machine-broadcast-its-ip-address-dynamically), https://askubuntu.com/questions/460371/trouble-using-ssh-and-avahi.

Solutions either advice to use something like `nmap` which as I've understood by running `nmap -v -sn 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8` tries to contact every IP on the net from a range (runs long and and range for ipv6 is large), install DNS server, cover discovery by hosthame when ip is known and lastly advise `avahi`.

I need only ip, no need for hostname, I prefer not install DHCP and DNS servers.

I've tried avahi and I can see ip and hostname of service via GUI in `avahi-discover`, but in `avahi-browse` only service name, no ip. How to get ip address in terminal for use in scripting?

Apart from avahi, it is my guess that in order for two PCs when local-linked not to assign themselves same ip addresses, they exchange their addresses for checking. Am I right here? Maybe in such case it is possible to obtain ip addresses at time of local-link connection being established, isn't it?

Comment: is this question about IPv4 only? Or only to iPv6? Because the beginning of your question seems to concern itself with IPv6, the rest with v4!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, as of now I would prefer solution for ipv6. what made you think "the rest" is about ipv4? Because of example of `nmap` with ipv4? just checked `nmap` has option for ipv6 too: `-6: Enable IPv6 scanning`.

Comment: well, the IPv4 address for `nmap`, yes, also, the mechanism you described for autoconfiguration is the IPv4 one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the mechanism was my guess. Where can I read one for ipv6? Thanks

Comment: The [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) wikipedia article has some very basic info, but links to [rfc4291](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.6)