# /usr/bin/host not picking up changes to /etc/hosts even after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, hosts

I have a Ubuntu Server 12.04 (`amd64`) machine on which, when I change `/etc/hosts`, the changes aren't picked up, even after a reboot. I am using `/usr/bin/host` to test, but none of the other programs seems to pick it up either.

This is a server and `nscd` and `dnsmasq` aren't installed. Also, the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains the line:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

so that I would expect it to work. I also checked that the `mtime` of the file changes with editing and tried running `service networking restart` (against all odds) and also `resolvconf -u`.

All commands where run as `root` where needed. The machine has network configured manually in `/etc/network/interfaces` and not via Network Manager (it isn't installed either).

Basically what I want to achieve is that the IP for a few hosts can be manipulated. The reason being that inside our network I get an IP to which I have no route, but I can use the external IP for that service via HTTPS.

What am I missing?

**Note:** no DNS server is locally running and the `nameserver` lines in `/etc/resolv.conf` (and the respective lines in `interfaces`) point to the DNS server that gives me the wrong IP.

**Also note:** I've searched on the web and read through the "similar questions", but my case doesn't seem to be covered.

`/etc/host.conf` is:

```
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The host command doesn't check the hosts file.  From the manpage:

```
host is a simple utility for performing DNS lookups.
```

If you want to test lookups while respecting the hosts file, then use ping or getent.

```
$ tail -1 /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   google.com
$ ping -c1 google.com | head -1
PING google.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
$ getent ahosts google.com
127.0.0.1       STREAM google.com
127.0.0.1       DGRAM  
127.0.0.1       RAW
```

Answer (score 2):

The `host` utility is used for DNS lookups. It doesn't care about hosts files or non-DNS methods of resolving a hostname. If you want to see how your system would resolve a hostname under normal circumstances (taking nsswitch.conf into account), you can use `getent`. The `host` utility should be reserved for DNS testing. Here is an example:

```
$ host foobar.com
foobar.com has address 69.89.31.56
foobar.com mail is handled by 0 foobar.com.
$ getent hosts foobar.com
10.188.14.16    foobar.com
```

Comment: @0xC0000022L That statement is incorrect. If you look at the manpage it uses `gethostbyaddr(3)`, which is a `libc` function.

Comment: @0xC0000022L `libc` functions are not system calls, so they won't show up in `strace`. Only things in the "2" section of manpages would show up in `strace`.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - also, since `getent` is part of `libc` on my system, it wouldn't make any sense for it to not use the library it is distributed with.

Answer (score 1):

Programs like `dig`, `host` and `nslookup` query the [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) only. They don't query other sources of host names such as `/etc/hosts`, NIS or LDAP.

In most setups, the easiest way to smoothly add host names locally is to run a DNS server. Running a DNS cache is a good idea anyway for performance. In other words, the fact that no DNS server is running locally is something to fix rather than something to work around.

[Dnsmasq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) is a common choice: it's widely available, small (it's used on many Linux-based routers) and easy to configure. Dnsmasq caches DNS requests and can serve additional names from a hosts file. It also provides a basic DHCP server suitable for small networks, but you don't have to use that part. If you have an isolated machine, run Dnsmasq on it. If you have a local network, run Dnsmasq (or some other equivalent software that's already there) on your router. See [How to make a machine accessible from the LAN using its hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname/16901#16901) for more information including how to set up Dnsmasq.