# hostname for computers in LAN

Tags: debian, networking

I am using Raspbian (like Debian) and I used this tutorial https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/ to setup my Raspbian as a wifi access point. Clients can connect to AP successfuly. But how can I do this - client should be able to open page http://local and it should point to my apache on AP. I don't want to set /etc/hosts on clients (they can vary) so I need to set it on AP directly and it should serve the right IP to clients when they open http://local.

I followed dnsmasq this [How to make a machine accessible from the LAN using its hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname) but it is not working (it worked for a while but then it stopped working)

How should I set my AP to serve the right name IP translation?

Comment: search for zeroconf, avahi or alternatively a more complicate solution, a local DNS. This question is quite regular here.

Comment: I am usinf dnsmasq. Maybe, some configuration tweeks for dnsmasq and it should work?

Answer (score 2):

I have my LAN connected through an asus rt-ac66u router, but most routers should work.
Go to the router configuration and under section LAN (static dhcp Manually Assigned IP) assign the IP address and hostname, as well as MAC address of the raspberry pi you want to reach inside your LAN. Doing so your raspberry pi will get always the same ip address from the DHCP server (my asus router in this precise case).
Now, from where you are trying to connect (another computer in your LAN for instance?), check the **/etc/resolv.conf** file and if not present, then just add the ip address of your router inside your LAN (gateway). In my case:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Now you should be able to ping it using the hostname of your raspberry...

**Extending answer regarding comment of *peter*


In your raspberry pi AP:**

You can use the **/etc/hosts.dnsmasq** file to add hostnames linked to ip addresses:

```
   192.168.1.10 host_1
   192.168.1.11 host_2
```

Dont forget to add this line to **/etc/dnsmasq.conf**:

```
   addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.dnsmasq
```

Now in your **/etc/hosts** of your AP:

```
   127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
   192.168.1.1 raspberry-pi
```

You should be able to access by using hostname from anywhere in your LAN:

- raspberry-pi
- host_1
- host_2

Comment: but I am trying to create AP directly in my Raspberry with build-in wifi module. I am not using router. Clients are connecting to RPi.

Comment: thanks @mmmint. I tried exactly the same steps. I have no idea why it stopped working. Now it is working again.

Comment: And again it didn't work. But when I manually run "sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart" in console then when I open http://mymachine.local it works ok. But when open "http://mymachine" this is not working. Strange. (I have both 192.168.0.2 for mymachine and mymachine.local in /etc/hosts)

Comment: Please extend your primary question with all this information and the contents of your configuration files. The more detailed you present it, the better we can try to help.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to define a local domain in dnsmasq; and define your hosts in `/etc/hosts` of the server/Linux running dnsmasq.

AS per the [dnsmasq - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq)

> Adding a custom domain
> It is possible to add a custom domain to hosts in your (local) network:
>
> ```
> local=/home.lan/  
> domain=home.lan
> ```
>
> In this example it is possible to ping a host/device (e.g. defined in your hosts file) as `hostname.home.lan`.
> Uncomment expand-hosts to add the custom domain to hosts entries:
>
> ```
> expand-hosts
> ```
>
> Without this setting, you'll have to add the domain to entries of  `/etc/hosts`.