# How to set-up a local DNS? Is it related to a real one, external one?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I run Raspberries on Jessie in a home network, with quite a bunch of devices.
I know many machines by IP, but it is slowly getting harder to keep on top of things.
I use one machine as a server (rpiserver): it does dnsmasq, squid, DHCP, syslog (for other machines), and think it can easily handle DNS as well... which in turn should give me more transparency in the network.

I own a domain on the Internet; say example.net, running www and mail.

1. Do I need to make my home network domain part of this domain? E.g.
   home.example.net? There is no need I can think of that these two
   domains "talk to each other" or external access is required to a
   local machine.
2. I am not too familiar with Linux, hence, I am wondering which files
   do I need to change to get this working?
3. Do I need to update the DHCP config and add the machine names, and
   it populates the DNS, or does it go the other way around?
4. Above all, is there a benefit running the local DNS for what I am describing?
5. I'd like an automatic solution; maybe update one 'thing' to
   propagate or resolve to/for others.
6. The router to the Internet does just that: WLAN/LAN routing; meaning
   I should be able to use dnsmasq, rather than setting up a DNS
   server?
7. Would having a local domain prevent a mail error when root sends
   notifications from rpiserver, and there is no 'domain' part to this
   name?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For a local home network, the easiest thing would be to just add all the hosts in everyone's `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: @Kusalananda: the problem is, there are machines which do neither have a hosts file nor the capability to have one. E.g Arduinos running the Ethernet stack... they get an IP address from rpiserver, but it would be good, if I could add the Arduino's name somewhere. Would this be dnsmasq or DHCP, where I add this name?

Comment: Most of your questions are already answered here: [How to make a machine accessible from the LAN using its hostname](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname)

Comment: @Gilles: thank you for the link; I used this brilliant description and it works for me!

Answer (score 2):

You say it runs `dnsmasq`. Apart from DHCP, that software *already* does DNS! Just edit your `/etc/hosts` on that machine, and it should work. There is certainly a benefit to using DNS for this; after all, that's what it was made for.

No, it will not work outside your network, unless you have an *NS record* at a higher zone. That's fine. As long as every host on your LAN uses your `dnsmasq` machine as their primary (or only) DNS server, you should be fine.

You don't *have* to make it part of a domain, but if you have one, it is good practice to do so.

Whether sending out mail will cause problems depends on many things. I suggest you try it out, and if it doesn't work, open a different question with some more details (it's really a completely different question, after all).

Comment: Edit /etc/hosts on THAT machine... is THAT the rpiserver running dnsmasq; where I need to enter all IP name matches?

Comment: Yes, on the machine that runs `dnsmasq`, obviously. Otherwise there's no way it could read it...

Comment: Hmm, what happens to hosts that get their IP dynamically? The DHCP server would know the names of the permanent leases, but what about dynamic ones?

Comment: If the client sends a name to the DHCP server, that should work.