# how to access homedir by root user

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I want to access `root` user's home directory `/root/`. However following commands dont lead me to the root directory.

> sudo -s
>
> cd ~

It leads to the home dir of regular user. How to access `/root` when using `sudo -s` to login as `root`. I am using `bash4` on `ubuntu12.04`.

Comment: same question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12228559/7552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo su - ###gets you to /root, as the root user.
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `cd /root` if you just want to go there :)

`sudo -s` may not update all environment variables so some aspects of your shell is still the old one. You can use `sudo -i`, or one of the methods described in [How do I run a command as the system administrator (root)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/250).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su # proper user switch
cd # goes to $HOME by default
```