# How to give to a user ability like root with visudo?

Tags: linux, sudo, users, group

I add this line to `visudo`, in order to give full permissions to yael user:

```
  yael ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But when I want to update the `/etc/hosts` file, I get permission denied:

```
 su – yael
 echo "10.10.10.10 yael_host">>/etc/hosts
 -bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied


 sudo  echo "10.10.10.10 yael_host">>/etc/hosts
-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied


 ls -ltr /etc/hosts
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 185 Aug  7 09:29 /etc/hosts
```

How can I give to user yael ability like root?

Comment: Add yael to group sudo. Logout and login. The entry `
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` Give all users in group sudo the rights. P:S If you like full granted rights. for comd-tools `sudo -s`

Comment: Your files are ok, i found a solution in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640011/append-text-to-file-from-command-line-without-using-io-redirection

Comment: You simply use sudoedit https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104429/how-do-i-edit-a-file-as-root

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**The source of the problem is that the output redirection is done by the shell (user yael) and not by `sudo echo`.**

In order to enforce that the writing to `/etc/hosts` will be done by user `root` instead of user `yael` - You can use the following format:

```
echo "10.10.10.10 yael_host" | sudo tee --append /etc/hosts
```

or

```
sudo sh -c "echo '10.10.10.10 yael_host'>>/etc/hosts"
```

Comment: @yael - did you try the solutions suggested in answer? did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/sudoers` (`visudo`) as follows:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
yael  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Then run:

```
sudo -- sh -c 'echo "10.10.10.10 yael_host">> /etc/hosts'
```

Or

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "10.10.10.10 yael_host">> /etc/hosts'
```

Comment: still get Permission denied

Comment: still -  echo "10.10.10.10 yael_host">>/etc/hosts
-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied

Comment: maybe need to update others files as /etc/group , etc

Comment: The redirections happen in yael's shell, before sudo is run.  they are not affected in any way by sudo.  the way to append text to a file you don't normally have perms to write to is with `... | sudo tee -a filename` (`-a` aka `--append`).  e.g. `echo "10.10.10.10 yael_host" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts` as in @Yaron's answer.