# Alternatives command and Centos7

Tags: centos, alternatives

I am trying to use the alternatives system on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core). I am trying to choose between multiple editors. I am following the tutorial here.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Applications_GUI_Multimedia/LINUX_ALTERNATIVES_HOWTO

Everything seems to be set up correctly. However, the default editor does not change.Please see the attached png file.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sudo alternatives --config myeditor`?

Comment: you need root permissions to change alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

The `alternatives` command ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives)) is a tool to *create, remove, maintain and display information about the symbolic links comprising the alternatives system*. So, you make **system-wide** changes with it and, thus, you need a user with elevated privileges. You either have to `sudo update-alternatives` (if [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) is installed and the user is a sudoer) or login as root with `su -` and then run said command. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3064/208450) to a question about how one runs commands that need root permissions may be helpful to you.