# crontab -e doesnt shows option to select editor - what to do?

Tags: centos, cron, non-root-user

I'm using Linux Centos 7, as a non-root user. When I want to add cron job that is not possible, I enter

```
crontab -e
```

I don't have option to select editor or to add cron job, just have blue ~ signs??

Also command select-editor does not exist.

Any help? What should I do?

Screenshoot:

http://prntscr.com/qxu06n

Comment: Can you show us what is the output?

Comment: What are your `VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables` (from `man crontab`)?

Comment: Sounds like you are using vi or vim editor.  Are the blue ~ signs in a vertical line on the left?

Comment: i uploaded screenshot

Comment: Yes you have. The option as @RudiC mentioned, is setting either `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` env. variable prior to run crontab -e. Here's e.g. how: `EDITOR=mcedit crontab -e`. This will use midnight commander editor. Replace it with the one of your choice.

Comment: First of all, you should press `:`, `q` and `Enter` to get out of the `vim` editor you're in. Or if you had already pressed the `i`, `a` or `s` keys by mischance, `Escape`, `:`, `q`, `!` and `Enter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is VIM (or possibly another `vi` clone).  You are in a text editor.  To add a cron job, just *edit using that editor*.

You do not have `select-editor` because that is part of the "sensible-utils" package on Debian. (Previously it was part of a "debianutils" package which was more obviously Debian-specific.)  That package is in the EPEL, not in CentOS proper.

The thing that RedHat has adopted from Debian is the "alternatives" system.  That controls what the `editor` command maps to.

There are several possibilities:

- Your `VISUAL` environment variable points to `vim` (or `vi`).
- Your `VISUAL` environment variable points to `editor`, and the currently selected alternative for `editor` is VIM.
- Your `VISUAL` environment variable is unset, the fallback is `editor`, and the currently selected alternative for `editor` is VIM.
- Your `VISUAL` environment variable is unset, the fallback is `vim` (or perhaps `vi`).

There are two approaches to changing the editor, if you want to use another one:

- Change what your `VISUAL` environment variable points to.  Depending from how you set it in the shell, this changes full-screen editor for just the current interactive shell session, or even just the current command (if you assign the variable as a prefix to a simple command).  You can of course set it in a login script.
- Unset your `VISUAL` environment variable and change the alternative for `editor`.  This changes the meaning of `editor` for everyone on the system, note.  It also depends from the assumption that `editor` is the fallback when the environment variable is unset.  That's a reasonable fallback to use on "alternatives" operating systems like Debian, OpenSUSE, and Fedora/CentOS/RHEL.  But the fallback logic is of course encoded in many individual commands and scripts and not every software author chooses `editor` as the fallback.

## Further reading

- [Alternatives command and Centos7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366664/5132)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477769/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). *[Unix editors and pagers](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/unix-editors-and-pagers.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 1):

To use a different editor, for example nano, for a one-time edit, run:

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

To make nano your default editor, add this to your profile which may be .bashrc or some other file:

```
export VISUAL="nano"
export EDITOR="nano"
```

Then reload your profile with :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/getting-started-nano