# listing all hardware details on Linux

Tags: linux, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [checking hardware on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/checking-hardware-on-linux)

I want to list all the hardware details about my system. To start with I've following things in my mind.

`processor` `memory` `bios` `hba`

I've got few details about processor like

`processor: Current Speed, Max Speed, Family, Manufacturer, Version, No of CPU's`

Can anybody expand the list for me of what other hardware details i need to figure out.

Comment: few more details 

`hostname` `ip` `pagesize` `hostid`

Comment: How could we know what _you_ need? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Mat: I need list of items which cover under each category. for ex: `processor: Current Speed, Max Speed, Family, Manufacturer, Version, No of CPU's`

Comment: take a look into output of lspci/lshw

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into `lspci`, `lshw`, `lscpu` and `dmidecode`.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu (perhaps others — it's in the `util-linux` package) also have `lscpu` which gives you lots of information about your CPU(s) and the way they're interrelated.

Comment: @Alexios Interesting. Will add on my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://ghazalisco.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/lspcilsusblshallshw/) is a little collection of the basic command-line utilities for this task.

Especially `lshw` and `lspci` are very useful. Occasionally `dmidecode` could carry additional information - I never ever had to use it, although.

As far as I know, `report-hw` is extremely useful in Debian-based systems (not tested).

`biosdevname` gives you the BIOS-given name of a device. It is needed rarely, but in some scenarios it could save life.

---

You didn't ask, but `hdparm` and `sdparm` are useful for harddisks and solid state drives, respectively. `smartctl` is for SMART-operations.

Answer (score 1):

I like to add `lsusb` and `lsdev` as well, but probably one of the best hints is:

Try [cfg2html](http://cfg2html.com/), this is a script that calls all other scripts to give you an overview about your system.