# Find out exact CPU model, Mainboard, RAM / server model?

Tags: debian, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting information on a machine's hardware in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/getting-information-on-a-machines-hardware-in-linux)

I have an "older" system here, something before 2005.

1) cat /proc/cpuinfo gives
    Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.00GHz
as model - how can I find out, which xeon exactly it is?

2) Same for RAM, how do I find out, which type of RAM (DDRx) it is?

3) How to find out the used mainboard? Especially is it possible to identify which server it is? (server = which ready-built system from which company)

It's a Debian system as far as I know, currently I don't have root access.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Do you have `lshw`?

Comment: My `/proc/cpuinfo` gives the actual model number (Exxxx), are you sure yours doesn't?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, unfortunately ):

Answer (score 6):

Debian should have the tool `dmidecode` available. You should find just about everything you need from there.

dmidecode: http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/

Comment: it says command not found ): note that I currently don't want to install/change anything on the system, even if possible without root access.

Comment: Can you reboot it? If so, you may be able to run a live CD with the required tools. Does it have a BMC (e.g. DRAC on Dell, xLOM on Suns, etc)? If so, you can get info via it. Otherwise, rebooting might show the details of the CPU/RAM.

Comment: The reboot will also show the hardware probing that happens at boot time in /var/log/dmesg with lots of useful hints.  Should help narrow the field a little

Comment: @charlesbridge following that logic, he should be able to just run `dmesg|less` to view the dmesg of the last boot without having to reboot